# Why can I not make schema changes in SQL Server when the table/view is linked to Access?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

I have my SQL Server view linked to MS Access. I opened my linked view in Access which opened a datasheet. When the view is opened in Access front end, I cannot save any changes in the SQL Server view. If I try to save my view in SQL Server. I get this error:

> Execution Timeout expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding

**Edit**

I do not even have to make any changes to the view. If the view is opened in MS Access and I hit <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> in SQL Server, I get the same error even if I have not made any changes to the view

Comment: I would guess that that Access view has locked the SQL Server table(s)

Comment: I guess this is  a common issue?

Comment: If you are using an editable grid against a table, guess what? You need to lock the table to permit those edits to occur. Not an issue when you are in the cosy closed world of Access alone. You may need to re-design your approach to overcome this, but well outside the scope of a comment and also not my specific expertise either.